# buku installation fails due to pre-existing file

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded buku program from github as follows:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jarun/Buku.git
```

Then

```
$ cd Buku

$ sudo make install

install -m755 -d /usr/local/bin
install -m755 -d /usr/local/share/man/man1
install: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/man/man1’: File exists
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

How can I get round this? the Makefile is as follows:

```
$ cat Makefile 

PREFIX ?= /usr/local
BINDIR ?= $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
MANDIR ?= $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/share/man/man1
DOCDIR ?= $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/share/doc/buku

.PHONY: all install uninstall

all:

install:
    install -m755 -d $(BINDIR)
    install -m755 -d $(MANDIR)
    install -m755 -d $(DOCDIR)
    gzip -c buku.1 > buku.1.gz
    install -m755 buku $(BINDIR)/buku
    install -m644 buku.1.gz $(MANDIR)
    install -m644 README.md $(DOCDIR)
    rm -f buku.1.gz

uninstall:
    rm -f $(BINDIR)/buku
    rm -f $(MANDIR)/buku.1.gz
    rm -rf $(DOCDIR)
```

As additional information:

```
$ namei -lx /usr/local/share/man/man1
f: /usr/local/share/man/man1
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root local
drwxr-xr-x root root share
drwxr-xr-x root root man
-rw-r--r-- root root man1
```

Comment: Add the output of `namei -lx /usr/local/share/man/man1` to the post, please.

Comment: ok muru I just did that

Comment: Any idea why you have a file named `/usr/local/share/man/man1` when it's supposed to be a directory? If it's not something you created on purpose, delete or move it and run `make` again.

Comment: man1 file should be removed. But what was wrong with installing [binary package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=buku) as simple as `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get install buku` ?

Comment: I did that and it worked fine but it installs the older version. I uninstalled/removed/purged it before trying this latest version.

Comment: Thank you muru. I renamed man1 (to man01) and tried again. This time it worked.  The contents of man01 seems to relate to cruft2 app which I must have installed a long time ago. I removed cruft2 to be on the safe side.